Voltage unexpected noise
I'm quite new to the electronic designs so might have made some horrible mistakes in the below circuit.  It works as expected but it has a problem.
The voltage at the output has some sort of noise fluctuating between 150mV pk-pk to around 250mV pk-pk with quite random frequency between 1MHz and 170kHz.
What are my options to reduce this noise?



Have you checked that you are not getting more than 5V on the A,B or W pins according to the absolute max from the datasheet of the digipot?

Your oscilloscope screenshot does not agree with your statement in the question - you state 150-250 mV pk-pk, and the oscilloscope says 2.54 V pk-pk. An order of magnitude higher

Where is the oscilloscope curve even measured? You have a node called VOUT and a connector called VOUT which contains a different node than VOUT

Are you following the requirements to output capacitor for LM1085?

So I'm taking measurements at the Vout label. Yes I've tried to follow as close as possible to the datashet of the ldo. The picture is right the values are at the bottom of the label. Regarding the limitation of the dpot yes it's software limited AND I've added a 5.1 zener across just to make sure

The zener will burn without some sort of limitation of current.

Yes after redesign of the circuit with the 1k in series with pot0 wiper and 3k on parallel with pot1 wiper I recon zener won't be needed.

Another thought on limiting impact of software error on output over-voltage from your comment on the 5.1V zener, could place a zener at the ADJ pin to ground with breakdown just above 5V - 1.25V.  Then the upper R1_equiv would provide some current limiting through the zener, and the Zener could continously hold the ADJ at a level that doesn't exceed 5V output by much.

This answer is mostly questions for you to investigate, but too much to cover for a comment.  First, is U2 properly grounded in your schematic?  The net dawn on U2-GND, which is also drawn to U11-1,12,13 config pins to strap them low, seems to be MISSING a global ground symbol.  You seem to imply by "It works as expected, but.." that U2 and U11 are already tested and seem to be functional.
Second, the schematic Note stating "Vout enabled by GPIO A6 set high", seems incorrect because the Q1 P-FET will be on when its gate is low (not high).  Also, using GPIO to directly control Q1 gate (even through R5) is bad practice if the high-side FET input voltage (Q1 source) can exceed GPIO max allowed voltage (VDD or +5V?), which will cause GPIO internal ESD diode to conduct because via pull-up R6 and lower the gate voltage, possibly enough to accidentally turn on Q1.  Instead, use the GPIO to drive the base (through small resistance) of a NPN BJT inverter with its collector connected to Q1 gate (keep the small R5 is fine) and to the R6 pull-up to source. With that modification A6 high would turn on Q1 and be safe to not overvoltage the GPIO.
Third, the schematic note says maximum intended output is 5V, but if VIN could be as high as 12V (from schematic note above J3) and since U11 (digital potentiometer) controls the effective R1 and R2 values (~65 to 5K each), then software could later accidentally set the R2/R1 ratio to a high value (much greater than 3). Then, the U3 LDO could easily be trying to output maximum possible voltage, which would be limited to the input voltage less 1.5V dropout (as high as 10.5V)u High output voltage would cause D6 (output protection diode) to conduct and likely smoke, as that diode is really capably of suppressing transients only. Alternatively, the software could incorrectly/accidentally set the effective R1 + R2 value too low (e.g., to ~130 ohms), and greatly exceed the U11 max allowed current for the pot(P) ports of 2.5mA (MCP 465X datasheet on pages 3 and 6).  Generally a bad practice to allow errant software to damage hardware.  A good alternative could be put an external 1K fixed resistor in series with the upper U11 wiper (i.e. between Vout and U11-5,6 P1W) to limit effective R1+R2 to greater than 1K Ohms. The lower U11 wiper could be in parallel with an external fixed 3K resistor, allowing effective R2 to be ~65 to 3K Ohm. This would limit the highest Vout voltage setting to R2_effective = 3K (wiper open) and R1_effective = 1K (wiper at 0 Ohms) to be 5V. Yet still allow software to set full range of Vout 5V to 1.25V.
Assuming above control issues are resolved or not yet discovered because Vin was low for testing, I'm hoping during output noise testing, the setting of the digi-pot (U11) has been held constant, or better yet, U11 has been removed from the prototype and replaced by the R1 fixed resistor and the R2 manual potentiometer while you are taking these measurements?  If not, start by doing that first to isolate the control circuit from the output circuit.  That should  eliminate/confirm if U11 or U2 causing noise onto ADJ input of LDO regulator (U3-1) is the problem, since any noise on ADJ will directly disturb the circuit output.  The ADJ pin filtering (C6 and C42) is already very large (47uF+10uF).
After confirming all is quiet on the ADJ input, if there is still an output noise issue, then next look at the circuit's output stage (i.e., the LM1085 LDO Regulator U3). When an LDO output is noisy, first thing I look at is the input and output capacitors, which have strict requirements on minimum value, ESR, and mounting inductance.  Were the layout guidelines in section 10 of the LM1085 datasheet considered during PCB design by keeping the input and output capacitors mounted close to U3?  Are these caps well connected to each other on ground side? And finally, is the ground used by low side of adjustment potentiometer (i.e. U11 pin 10, or R2 gnd side) well connected to final output GND at J4 pin 2.  The LDO datasheet recommends 10uF input cap and 10uF output cap, with output cap needing some low ESR for regulator stability (datasheet section 7.4.2).  The output caps (C3 100uF and C8 0.1uF) seem likely OK, but I'm worried about the LDO input cap design.  I'm guessing C1 bulk cap (2200uF) is close to J3 input rather than close to U3, and perhaps C7 (0.1uF) is near U2 or U11 power/gnd pins and far from U3. If C1 is not really serving as good input cap, I'd try adding a 10uF cap as directly as possible between U3 pin 3 and C3's ground pin, assuming C3 should already be close to U3, and see if that helps.

Thanks such a great answer !

Indeed i was testing the circuit with d-pot removed and replaced with fixed resistors, with the same results. I've checked and the input voltage source has the same /similar noise, i can't replace the source so I'm looking to somehow get rid of that noise at the outputs. (I though about using opamp voltage forwarder, but i'm not that experienced yet to confirm my idea. )
Experimentally i already tried what if... yes the dpot are getting smoky hot and will get damaged )
with the BJT NPN i have bc337 laying around which i could try would it fit as the inverter ?

A proper functioning LDO will provide a Power-Supply-Rejection-Ratio (PSSR) that greatly reduces noise on it's input from appearing on the output....that is assuming the input noise source has also not coupled to ADJ control pin.   For LM1085 see datasheet Figure 6. Ripple Rejection vs Frequency.  Rejection drops as frequency of input noise is higher, best rejection for low freq.   If you want more high freq filtering on the input, I'd add a 1uF ceramic very close to the LDO input.

BC377 should work as GPIO inverter, place 1K or higher between GPIO pin and the base to limit the current out of the GPIO when high, emitter to gnd, collector to R5/R6 junction to control Q1.

I was able to test the setup with resisters and BC337 and it seems to be ok, with one exception, at the output i was only able to get maximum of around 3.86V, Replacing the 3K with variable 5K allows me ro reach around 4V
Here is my updated design:
https://imgur.com/j4JOgog
Before I'll order a PCB  is there anything fundamentally wrong with it ?

The rest of new schematic: (1) make sure both U2 GND pins connect to ground plane, one seems to only connect to U1. (2) still recommend separate 10 uF cap for input to U3 pin 3, with ground close to C3 ground connection, both right next to U3.  (3) R5 could be zero ohms to start, but otherwise Q2 looks good.

In new R1/R2/U11 topology, the new R2_effective is going to be the P0 setting in parallel with external R2, and new R1_effective is 1K in series with P1 setting. My mind was thinking P0 goes to infinity (open), but max is actually 5K unless force open the internal switches. So for P0=5k, and P1=0, Vout = 1.25V * (1+ (5K internal || 3K external)/1K = 3.6V, and 1.25V(1 + 5K||5K/1K) = 4.3V, which explains why can't Vout can't reach 5.0V. To improve: fix R2 at 3K (disconnect P0) and raise P1 setting to control voltage, but then minimum Vout limited to 1.75V. or keep thinking??

I figured out that the wiper or any other end of the pot can be actually disconnected completely by setting the register value. This solves the issue. In reality my load is ok with voltages between 2.2- 4v so still ok as is. But for the sake of having this full I'm experimenting with various register settings.

The noise source might be prior to the regulator, and the regulator would not do well to remove such high frequencies. you should measure at the input of the regulator too, being sure to attach the ground clip of the 'scope probe near the regulator, and also to probe as close to the regulator as possible.
To me it doesn't look like noise that the regulator would produce. Switch off nearby appliances like TV, LED lights etc, see if that improves things.
You have 10μF+47μF=57μF (C2 and C6) of capacitance at the adjust pin of the regulator, implying that you expect the input to contain heavy ripple. That seems a little excessive to me. I suggest you try removing those capacitances, as a test. I don't think you need both of them, just one situated close to the adjust pin, and unless you have a good reason for it, I don't think it should be more than 10μF.
Temporarily remove the digital potentiometer from the adjustment system, and replace it with a fixed, known resistance, to see if that pot IC maybe contributing to noise.
Proper grounding will be important in this application, especially when using low-dropout devices like the LM1085. If the ground node is long and sprawling, with stuff connected all along it, you'll definitely invite problems. In fact, any long wires (especially those associated with the adjustment pin of the regulator) will be problematic. Keep paths short.

My initial plan was to add a ground plane on the bottom layer of pcb, but taking this to account should it be reduced to only the input part of the pcb?

use as big of ground plane/fill as you can, and tie all the IC grounds and input/output cap grounds together using this plane.  By "long and sprawling" I think that means if you are forced to route ground as wide traces, rather than a fill/plane.
